# Integrat @chilkat/ck-electron16-win-ia32 in electron project

Tags: node.js, electron, chilkat

Actualy I try to intgrat
but I face to this exception my node version is 16.3.2 32bit

```
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\electron_project_X32\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:630 Error: Loading non-context-aware native module in renderer: '\\?\C:\Users\PC\Desktop\electron_project_X32\node_modules\@chilkat\ck-electron16-win-ia32\chilkat.node'. See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397.
    at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5)
```

and this is may package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "electron": "^16.1.0",
    "electron-packager": "^15.4.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.7",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chilkat/ck-electron16-win-ia32": "^9.50.89",
    "@chilkat/ck-node16-win-ia32": "^9.50.89",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "crypto-md5": "^1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "electron-tabs": "^0.15.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "ffi-napi": "^4.0.3",
    "freemarker": "^2.0.1",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.0",
    "node-key-sender": "^1.0.11",
    "node-notifier": "^10.0.1",
    "npm": "^8.5.3",
    "pkg": "^5.5.2",
    "serialport": "^10.4.0",
    "sudo-prompt": "^9.2.1",
    "through2": "^4.0.2",
    "websocket": "^1.0.34"
  }
```

I try to set this **app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false** in main.js but it don't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED BY @chilkat Software by upgrading the current version of chilkat/ck-electron16-win64  and win32